# Generating a string of repeated chars in Swift

Tags: swift

I was wondering if there are more neat way to do this in Swift:

```
var s = ""
for _ in 1...10 {
    s += " "
}
```

Answer (score 7):

There is a `String` constructor for this problem:

```
var s = String(count: 10, repeatedValue: Character(" "))
```

Comment: For Swift 5+ it seems the signature as changed to `String(repeating: " ", count:10)`